# Unable to access Google's Maven repository: Gradle stuck at resolving dependencies

Tags: android, maven, gradle

It seems that Google's Maven repository may be experiencing downtime, as I am unable to access https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/index.html, and the `wget https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/index.html` command has timed out. Additionally, https://maven.google.com/web/index.html appears to be completely empty. Any suggestions on how to proceed would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're having issues when accessing Google's Maven repository, make sure you can download the repository master index.

```
curl https://dl.google.com/android/maven2/master-index.xml
```

In my case, I couldn't download the master index and assumed that the service is down.

Additionally, you can check if the dependencies are listed on https://maven.google.com/web/index.html